# Why FOSUserBundle has two UserManager Classes?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, usermanager

I went a little bit into the FOSUserBundle and recognized that this Bundle has one UserManager in the directory Model and another one in the directory Doctrine.

Is there someone, who can tell me the reason for this? 
I only want to know it for interest.

Comment: Not only two of them. Propel/ also has a UserManager class. And it extends BaseUserManager. Since there are some differences in implementation for different databases.

Comment: Ah ok, that means, if I use only doctrine it would be usefull to put all the stuff in the model/ userManager ?